# Still receive syntax error for dynamic import with babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import when running with mocha

Tags: node.js, webpack, mocha.js, babeljs

All babel modules/plugins are on the latest version of babel v6.
Mocha is on v4.0.1.

Setup:

```
// .babelrc
{
   presets: [
      "stage-3",
      [
         "env",
         {
           "targets": {
              "browsers": [
                "last 2 versions"
              ],
              "node": "current"
           }
         }
      ]
      "react"
   ],
   plugins: ["transform-runtime", "syntax-dynamic-import"]
}


// mocha.opts
--recursive
--reporter progress
--require babel-polyfill
--require babel-register
--timeout 20000
```

So when I run my test suite I still get:
[error stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xZxB.png).

I would have to imagine it has something to do with babel-register and syntax-dynamic-import not working together correctly. Because when I use it with babel-loader in webpack I don't get any syntax errors on transpile.

Comment: figured it out. I moved to dynamic-import-node. I had previously tried this and it was still failing. The reason that it was still failing was because something was getting cached somewhere. Could be from mocha or babel. So if I changed the file or the test `dynamic-import-node` started working as expected.

Comment: Not sure why `syntax-dynamic-import` doesn't work with `babel-register` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer on babeljs slack from Satyajit Sahoo cleared things up for me:

> `syntax-dynamic-import` will only enable the syntax in babylon, which means it babylon can parse the code without syntax error. the code `import(...)` is still there, which node doesn’t understand and you still need to transpile it. `dynamic-import-node` transpiles the `import(...)` to `require` which node understands. On client, the transpilation step is not necessary since Webpack understands the syntax and does the bundling.