# babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import does not transpile

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I think I correctly configured `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` but it would still not transpile my dynamic import.

Node: v8.11.3

package.json:

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    ...
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --open --hot --progress",
  ...
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    ...
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
...
{
  test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx?$/],
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  },
},
...
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

AsyncComp.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const Loading = () => (<div>Loading...</div>);

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./CompRaw'),
  loading: Loading,
})

export default class AsyncComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableComponent />;
  }
}
```

executing `yarn dev` results in:

```
/home/somepath/src/components/AsycnComp.jsx
  7:17  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token import
```

Why is the dynamic `import()` not transpiled? How can I fix it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001697/2352587

Comment: Its running on the client, so I would not need dynamic-import-node. However, I tried it again, and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Ah okay! I think you also need `react-loadable/babel`. See the discussion here: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/pull/35#issuecomment-337156641

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using `react-loadable/babel` as babel plugin still does not solve the issue. I tried adding it in .bablerc and in webpack babel-loder options. Also I tried it on its own and together with `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`

Comment: I tried their example, it's working fine for me. `react-loadable/babel` is optional too.

Comment: Thanks for verifying! Then it must be something else.

Comment: it was a misconfiguration of eslint (see own answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is good and the error originates from using the `eslint-loader` but not installing `babel-eslint` plugin which would enable support for dynamic imports.

This solved the issue

```
yarn add babel-eslint -D
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  ...
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```